# How to disable number input types using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a small project that contains a php page that will ask the user to enter a number of questions for a test and after writing a number for example 10 he will then allocate number of question for each type of the exam (addition, subtraction, multiplication, division) until the number of questions finish for example after choosing 10 total questions he can then choose 5 in addition 3 in multiplication and 2 in division but he cant allocate anymore questions because the 10 total questions have finished. And he is allocating these numbers in a number input type in html so I want to get the first input type which is the total number of questions and then decrement that number every time he increase any of the exam types(addition, ..) and when it reaches 0 it will disable the input types here is what I did so far:

```js
var numInput = document.getElementById('numInput');
var Input1 = document.getElementById('Input1');
var Input2 = document.getElementById('Input2');
var Input3 = document.getElementById('Input3');
var Input4 = document.getElementById('Input4');

Input1.disabled = true;
Input2.disabled = true;
Input3.disabled = true;
Input4.disabled = true;

var Checker = setInterval(function Checker() {
var numValue = numInput.value;
//thats what I tried to do to solve my problem but it didn't work properly because it must decrement only 1 but the condition will still be true so it will decrement for ever or at least that is what I think.
if (Input1.value > 0) {
 numValue = numValue - 1;
}
//and this part is working fine.
if (numValue > 0) {
 Input1.disabled = false;
 Input2.disabled = false;
 Input3.disabled = false;
 Input4.disabled = false;
} else if (numValue <= 0) {
 Input1.disabled = true;
 Input2.disabled = true;
 Input3.disabled = true;
 Input4.disabled = true;
}
}, 100);
```

```html
<form method="GET" action="">
 <h2>How many questions do you want to answer?</h2>
 <input id="numInput" type="number" name="Text" value="0" min="0"><br> 
 <h2>Addition: </h2>&nbsp<input id="Input1" type="number" name="Text" value="0" min="0"><br>
 <h2>Subtraction: </h2>&nbsp<input id="Input2" type="number" name="Text" value="0" min="0"><br>
 <h2>Multiplication: </h2>&nbsp<input id="Input3" type="number" name="Text" value="0" min="0"><br>
 <h2>Division: </h2>&nbsp<input id="Input4" type="number" name="Text" value="0" min="0">
</form>
```

And I don't have any idea on how can I solve this so please help me.

Comment: Are you sure all of your users will be male?

Comment: @Dai What do you mean?

Comment: You should just not ask for the total number of questions. Let people just enter whatever they want in the four other inputs, and you're done. Otherwise, what will you do if user inputs everything and then changes the total number?

Comment: @trincot The thing is this is for learning purpose so it was a rule to let the user choose the total number of questions however I can just put it in another page or something so that the user can't change it again

Comment: @MohammadSherif You used male pronouns a lot in your opening statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of decrementing numValue, you should compare it with sum of other inputs

```
function Checker() {
var sum=parseInt(Input1.value)+parseInt(Input2.value)+parseInt(Input3.value)+parseInt(Input4.value);
var numValue = numInput.value;
if (numValue > sum) 
{
    Input1.disabled = false;
    Input2.disabled = false;
    Input3.disabled = false;
    Input4.disabled = false;
} else  
{
    Input1.disabled = true;
    Input2.disabled = true;
    Input3.disabled = true;
    Input4.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Also, better then setInterval, use [onchange event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp)

```
numInput.addEventListener("change", Checker);
Input1.addEventListener("change", Checker);
Input2.addEventListener("change", Checker);
Input3.addEventListener("change", Checker);
Input4.addEventListener("change", Checker);
```

Comment: When I used the onchange event it was working weird so I used the set Interval again can you tell me why that happened for example I could increase every type of questions above the total number of questions by 1

Comment: also can you tell me a way to disable the input type number from writing manually because I can basically write 0 beside any number and it will be larger than the total number and a way to pass that sum to a php session because I will need that sum in another page

Comment: I tested it with onchange and it worked ok. Maybe you change condition to >=?

Comment: If you really want to disable input  from writing manualy you can set it as read only and than make your own increment/decrement buttons. But i think better way is to use onchange function to restore previous value if new value is over the limit.

Comment: Can you help me please with the onchange function?